# Что делать, когда правку незаслуженно не принимают с одного лишь голоса автора

Tags: поддержка, статус-так-задумано, отклонённые-правки

Впервые столкнулся с тем, что нормальную информативную правку (даже с подробным комментарием) отклонил сам автор вопроса.

Речь идет о правке https://ru.stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/52125. Вкратце её поясню: автором вопроса дается ссылка на страницу документации и рекомендация воспользоваться поиском для нахождения нужной главы. Я поменял ссылку на ссылку с якорем, чтобы у пользователя, перешедшего по ссылке, открылся сразу необходимый раздел. Кроме того я убрал излишние теги, которые, как мне кажется, захламляют ресурс. В сообществе разработчиков Symfony принято теги именовать как `symfony` вместо `symfony2` и `symfony3`. `symfony2` на английском SO остался как основной, так как до сих пор ни один модератор не принял это во внимание, хотя в твиттере уже несколько раз искались люди, способные это сделать. У Symfony версий 2 и 3 - общая кодовая база, третья версия лишь ломает некоторую обратную совместимость со старыми версиями (совсем старыми), которую можно предотвратить, воспользовавшись инструкциями по апгрейду. Таким образом почти все вопросы, которые связаны с Symfony3, связаны также и с Symfony2. То есть, по сути все вопросы по Symfony при текущем раскладе будут иметь теги `symfony`, `symfony2`, `symfony3` (как у автора вопроса). Такое поведение надо искоренять до того, как это войдет в привычку.

Что следует делать в таком случае?

Писать в комментарии (как я сейчас сделал): мне кажется, что это оффтоп и разведение флуда. Но других способов я не нашел. Может, я просто не так искал? Вообще, почему правку может отклонить один лишь человек? Почему за правку не голосуют несколько ревьюеров?

Comment: правку может принять/отклонить тс единолично, вчера натыкался на правку в которой один ревьювер отклонил правку, тс же её принял, итог правка принялась

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Автор имеет право единолично принять или отклонить предлагаемую правку. А если правка не проверяется (т.е. от участника с 2000+ репутации), то автор может откатить её. Это нормальное поведение сайта.

Что касается самой правки.

**Во-первых**, вы дополнили ссылку. Но на самом деле она стала вести туда же, куда и вела, т.к. вы изменили только отображаемый текст, но не URL:

```
[http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/installation.html#checking-symfony-application-configuration-and-setup][1]
[1]: http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/installation.html
```

Проверьте: такая ссылка не содержит якоря в URL.

> [http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/installation.html#checking-symfony-application-configuration-and-setup](http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/installation.html)

Чтобы изменить ссылку в разметке Makrdown, идите в «подвал» текста, найдите там список ссылок и поменяйте нужную. Вообще, уточнение ссылки — это хорошо.

**Во-вторых**, при редактировании ссылки вы почему-то удалили фрагмент "Charter: ctrl+f ->"

**В-третьих** вы удалили метки, поставленные автором. Приведу здесь аргументацию:

> Зачем плодить огромное количество тегов идентичных? Сообщество разработчиков Symfony в лице Фабьена Потенсье (создателя Symfony) уже высказывалось по поводу того, что на английском StackOverflow необходимо избегать тегов symfony3 и symfony2 в пользу тега symfony.

Возможно, вы правы и разбивать [symfony](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/symfony) на версионные метки действительно нецелесообразно. Но в таком случае порядок действий должен быть такой:

1. Задайте вопрос на Мете с предложением объединить метки. Приведите аргументацию, в том числе ссылки на высказывание Фабьена Потеньсе. Объясните, почему версионные метки не привносят ничего полезного в вопросы.
2. Привлеките к этому обсуждению участников, у которых высокий рейтинг по обсуждаемым меткам. Можно написать комментарий к любому их ответу на вопрос по этой метке. Что-то вроде «`Пожалуйста, примите участие в обсуждении синонимизации меток [tag:symfony]. http://meta.ru.stackoverflow.com/q/2219/`» (только число другое будет)
3. Если вы всех убедили и сообщество поддерживает идею объединения, то мы их синонимизируем. Это стандартный и простой механизм, по меткам достаточно участников для голосования. В случае чего, сможет помочь модератор.

А просто так удалять метки с одного вопроса не стоит.

**Итог:**

- Испорчена ссылка
- Удалена часть текста
- Спорная правка меток.

По первому и второму пункту правка однозначно испортила вопрос — и была заслуженно отклонена. По третьему пункту стоит поднять отдельное обсуждение.

Comment: Да, косячнул с ссылкой. Отправил новую правку с исправленной ссылкой. По тегам сейчас создам на мете вопрос.

Comment: @MichaelSivolobov: и снова удалили `*Charter*: **ctrl+f** -> **` :)

Comment: Вообще не понимаю, причем тут слово Charter. Вполне возможно, что имелось ввиду Chapter (как глава), но тогда лучше было назвать Section (как раздел), но рекомендация поиска по Ctrl+F становится бессмысленной, если ссылка ведет на нужный раздел.

Comment: @MichaelSivolobov: ну, глава — это как минимум chaPter, да. Думаю, что лучше всего URL оставить только в подвале, а в [text][1] написать что-то осмысленное, например как раз «глава ...»

Comment: @MichaelSivolobov: вот как-то так.

Comment: пока редактировал кто-то уже принял правку:-)

Comment: @MichaelSivolobov: это я был. Можно принять правку с последующим редактированием. Это случай, когда правку можно принять единолично,  не будучи автором сообщения.

Comment: Добавил вопрос по поводу тегов: http://meta.ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/2221/Необходимо-навести-порядок-в-тегах-по-фреймворку-symfony. Теперь я пытаюсь понять, как мне найти участников, у кого высокий рейтинг по обсуждению меток?